# Laravel validation based on a variable

Tags: php, laravel

This is my insert function in controller. How can I validate $establishment_code as unique with validatedData? Now I am using $check to validate that. But I want to validate it with validatedData.

```
public function establishment_insert(Request $request){
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|max:190',
                'code' => 'required|max:2',
                'district-id' => 'required|max:20',
            ]);


            $establishment_code = 'AS'.strtoupper(request('code'));

            $check = Establishment::where('code', '=', $establishment_code)->first();

            if($check){
                return redirect('establishments/'.$establishment->district_id)->with('failed', 'Establishment code already exists!');
            } else{
                // Insert to db.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try with **Validator**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data['code'] = 'AS'.strtoupper(request('code'));
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
             'name' => 'required|max:190',
              'code' => 'required|max:2|unique:establishments',
              'district-id' => 'required|max:20',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('your route')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has inbuilt validation rule named `unique`. You can use `unique` for the same

```
'code' => 'required|max:2|unique:establishments,code',
```

[Laravel -> Validation -> Rule Unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 0):

modify the request data

```
    $request->merge([
        'code' => 'AS'.strtoupper(request('code')),
    ]);

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|max:190',
                'code' => 'required|max:2|unique:establishments,code',
                'district-id' => 'required|max:20',
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your validate as below :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
     'name' => 'required|max:190',
     'code' => 'required|max:2',
     'district-id' => 'required|max:20',
     'code' => [function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
       $establishment_code = 'AS'.strtoupper($value);
       $check = Establishment::where('code', '=', $establishment_code)->first();
       if (!$check) {
           $fail(':attribute not found'); // error massage
       }
     }]
 ]);
```

Refer : https://laravel-news.com/custom-validation-rule-objects